# Attributes in DB using active records not updated even when save gives no errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, save

My codes are relatively simple.

```
    if params[:job][:payment_method_token] == "cash"
     @job.payment_type = :cash
    else
     @job.payment_type = :credit_card
    end

    @job.save
```

Saving did not give any errors and returns true. I have used byebug and have verified that it did go into the else block and executed the `@job.payment_type = :credit_card`. Unfortunately, when i check `@job.payment_type`, it returns "cash". How is it possible that saving doesn't return errors but yet the attribute is not updated? Really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: What are the changes of a library used by thousands of projects failing at this basic task. Nearly zero! So, the problem is not in this code. Probably, giving surrounding code will help.

Comment: @Uzbekjon is correct. You should probably give more context about the job ActiveRecord class. For instance, what's the type of payment_type column? Also, what's the SQL executed in the rails logs?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I checked the model just to realize a team member used the same name for a method, "payment_type". So that was the cause of the problem.